# PHPUnit: post contents of file to an endpoint

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I am writing a test for an application that takes in pullrequestevents from github.

As part of that, I want to post the pullrequestevent JSON as supplied by GitHub, to ensure it is parsed and stored correctly.

but the supplied method in phpunit $this->post is expecting an array.

this is my test

```
public function  testPullRequestEventCanBePosted()
{
    $content = File::get('./sampleRequests/openPullRequest.json');
    $response = $this->post('/pullrequest', $content->toArray());
    $response->assertSuccessful();
}
```

and this is the json file

```
{
  "action": "open",
  "number": 2,
  "pull_request": {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/pulls/1",
    "id": 191568743,
    "node_id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0MTkxNTY4NzQz",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World/pull/1",
    "diff_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World/pull/1.diff",
    "patch_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World/pull/1.patch",
    "issue_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/issues/1",
    "number": 2,
    "state": "open",
    "locked": false,
    "title": "Update the README with new information",
    "user": {
      "login": "Codertocat",
      "id": 21031067,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIxMDMxMDY3",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/21031067?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "body": "This is a pretty simple change that we need to pull into master.",
    "created_at": "2018-05-30T20:18:30Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-30T20:18:50Z",
    "closed_at": "2018-05-30T20:18:50Z",
    "merged_at": null,
    "merge_commit_sha": "414cb0069601a32b00bd122a2380cd283626a8e5",
    "assignee": null,
    "assignees": [

    ],
    "requested_reviewers": [

    ],
    "requested_teams": [

    ],
    "labels": [

    ],
    "milestone": null,
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/pulls/1/commits",
    "review_comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/pulls/1/comments",
    "review_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/pulls/comments{/number}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/issues/1/comments",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/statuses/34c5c7793cb3b279e22454cb6750c80560547b3a",
    "head": {
      "label": "Codertocat:changes",
      "ref": "changes",
      "sha": "34c5c7793cb3b279e22454cb6750c80560547b3a",
      "user": {
        "login": "Codertocat",
        "id": 21031067,
        "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIxMDMxMDY3",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/21031067?v=4",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat",
        "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/followers",
        "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/following{/other_user}",
        "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/gists{/gist_id}",
        "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
        "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/subscriptions",
        "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/orgs",
        "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/repos",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/events{/privacy}",
        "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/received_events",
        "type": "User",
        "site_admin": false
      },
      "repo": {
        "id": 135493233,
        "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMzU0OTMyMzM=",
        "name": "Hello-World",
        "full_name": "Codertocat/Hello-World",
        "owner": {
          "login": "Codertocat",
          "id": 21031067,
          "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIxMDMxMDY3",
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/21031067?v=4",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false
        },
        "private": false,
        "html_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World",
        "description": null,
        "fork": false,
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World",
        "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/forks",
        "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/keys{/key_id}",
        "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/collaborators{/collaborator}",
        "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/teams",
        "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/hooks",
        "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/issues/events{/number}",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/events",
        "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/assignees{/user}",
        "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/branches{/branch}",
        "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/tags",
        "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/git/blobs{/sha}",
        "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/git/tags{/sha}",
        "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/git/refs{/sha}",
        "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/git/trees{/sha}",
        "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/statuses/{sha}",
        "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/languages",
        "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/stargazers",
        "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/contributors",
        "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/subscribers",
        "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/subscription",
        "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/commits{/sha}",
        "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/git/commits{/sha}",
        "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/comments{/number}",
        "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/issues/comments{/number}",
        "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/contents/{+path}",
        "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/compare/{base}...{head}",
        "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/merges",
        "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/{archive_format}{/ref}",
        "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/downloads",
        "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/issues{/number}",
        "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/pulls{/number}",
        "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/milestones{/number}",
        "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
        "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/labels{/name}",
        "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/releases{/id}",
        "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/deployments",
        "created_at": "2018-05-30T20:18:04Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-30T20:18:50Z",
        "pushed_at": "2018-05-30T20:18:48Z",
        "git_url": "git://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World.git",
        "ssh_url": "git@github.com:Codertocat/Hello-World.git",
        "clone_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World.git",
        "svn_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World",
        "homepage": null,
        "size": 0,
        "stargazers_count": 0,
        "watchers_count": 0,
        "language": null,
        "has_issues": true,
        "has_projects": true,
        "has_downloads": true,
        "has_wiki": true,
        "has_pages": true,
        "forks_count": 0,
        "mirror_url": null,
        "archived": false,
        "open_issues_count": 1,
        "license": null,
        "forks": 0,
        "open_issues": 1,
        "watchers": 0,
        "default_branch": "master"
      }
    },
    "base": {
      "label": "Codertocat:master",
      "ref": "master",
      "sha": "a10867b14bb761a232cd80139fbd4c0d33264240",
      "user": {
        "login": "Codertocat",
        "id": 21031067,
        "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIxMDMxMDY3",
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/21031067?v=4",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat",
        "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/followers",
        "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/following{/other_user}",
        "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/gists{/gist_id}",
        "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
        "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/subscriptions",
        "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/orgs",
        "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/repos",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/events{/privacy}",
        "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/received_events",
        "type": "User",
        "site_admin": false
      },
      "repo": {
        "id": 135493233,
        "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMzU0OTMyMzM=",
        "name": "Hello-World",
        "full_name": "Codertocat/Hello-World",
        "owner": {
          "login": "Codertocat",
          "id": 21031067,
          "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIxMDMxMDY3",
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/21031067?v=4",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false
        },
        "private": false,
        "html_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World",
        "description": null,
        "fork": false,
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World",
        "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/forks",
        "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/keys{/key_id}",
        "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/collaborators{/collaborator}",
        "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/teams",
        "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/hooks",
        "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/issues/events{/number}",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/events",
        "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/assignees{/user}",
        "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/branches{/branch}",
        "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/tags",
        "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/git/blobs{/sha}",
        "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/git/tags{/sha}",
        "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/git/refs{/sha}",
        "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/git/trees{/sha}",
        "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/statuses/{sha}",
        "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/languages",
        "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/stargazers",
        "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/contributors",
        "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/subscribers",
        "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/subscription",
        "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/commits{/sha}",
        "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/git/commits{/sha}",
        "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/comments{/number}",
        "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/issues/comments{/number}",
        "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/contents/{+path}",
        "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/compare/{base}...{head}",
        "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/merges",
        "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/{archive_format}{/ref}",
        "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/downloads",
        "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/issues{/number}",
        "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/pulls{/number}",
        "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/milestones{/number}",
        "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
        "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/labels{/name}",
        "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/releases{/id}",
        "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/deployments",
        "created_at": "2018-05-30T20:18:04Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-30T20:18:50Z",
        "pushed_at": "2018-05-30T20:18:48Z",
        "git_url": "git://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World.git",
        "ssh_url": "git@github.com:Codertocat/Hello-World.git",
        "clone_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World.git",
        "svn_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World",
        "homepage": null,
        "size": 0,
        "stargazers_count": 0,
        "watchers_count": 0,
        "language": null,
        "has_issues": true,
        "has_projects": true,
        "has_downloads": true,
        "has_wiki": true,
        "has_pages": true,
        "forks_count": 0,
        "mirror_url": null,
        "archived": false,
        "open_issues_count": 1,
        "license": null,
        "forks": 0,
        "open_issues": 1,
        "watchers": 0,
        "default_branch": "master"
      }
    },
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/pulls/1"
      },
      "html": {
        "href": "https://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World/pull/1"
      },
      "issue": {
        "href": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/issues/1"
      },
      "comments": {
        "href": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/issues/1/comments"
      },
      "review_comments": {
        "href": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/pulls/1/comments"
      },
      "review_comment": {
        "href": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/pulls/comments{/number}"
      },
      "commits": {
        "href": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/pulls/1/commits"
      },
      "statuses": {
        "href": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/statuses/34c5c7793cb3b279e22454cb6750c80560547b3a"
      }
    },
    "author_association": "OWNER",
    "merged": false,
    "mergeable": true,
    "rebaseable": true,
    "mergeable_state": "clean",
    "merged_by": null,
    "comments": 0,
    "review_comments": 1,
    "maintainer_can_modify": false,
    "commits": 1,
    "additions": 1,
    "deletions": 1,
    "changed_files": 1
  },
  "repository": {
    "id": 135493233,
    "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMzU0OTMyMzM=",
    "name": "Hello-World",
    "full_name": "Codertocat/Hello-World",
    "owner": {
      "login": "Codertocat",
      "id": 21031067,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIxMDMxMDY3",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/21031067?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "private": false,
    "html_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World",
    "description": null,
    "fork": false,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/forks",
    "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/keys{/key_id}",
    "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/teams",
    "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/hooks",
    "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/issues/events{/number}",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/events",
    "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/assignees{/user}",
    "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/branches{/branch}",
    "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/tags",
    "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/git/refs{/sha}",
    "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/git/trees{/sha}",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/statuses/{sha}",
    "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/languages",
    "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/stargazers",
    "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/contributors",
    "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/subscription",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/commits{/sha}",
    "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/git/commits{/sha}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/comments{/number}",
    "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/issues/comments{/number}",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/contents/{+path}",
    "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/merges",
    "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/downloads",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/issues{/number}",
    "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/pulls{/number}",
    "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/milestones{/number}",
    "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/labels{/name}",
    "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/releases{/id}",
    "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Codertocat/Hello-World/deployments",
    "created_at": "2018-05-30T20:18:04Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-30T20:18:50Z",
    "pushed_at": "2018-05-30T20:18:48Z",
    "git_url": "git://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World.git",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:Codertocat/Hello-World.git",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World.git",
    "svn_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat/Hello-World",
    "homepage": null,
    "size": 0,
    "stargazers_count": 0,
    "watchers_count": 0,
    "language": null,
    "has_issues": true,
    "has_projects": true,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": true,
    "forks_count": 0,
    "mirror_url": null,
    "archived": false,
    "open_issues_count": 1,
    "license": null,
    "forks": 0,
    "open_issues": 1,
    "watchers": 0,
    "default_branch": "master"
  },
  "sender": {
    "login": "Codertocat",
    "id": 21031067,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIxMDMxMDY3",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/21031067?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/Codertocat",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/Codertocat/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  }
}
```

What method do I need to use to post this to the endpoint? is it a case of installing something like guzzle?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what results you might be getting at this point, but it looks like you are missing to decode the file contents as a proper JSON object:

```
// get plaintext contents from the json file stub
$plaintext = File::get('./sampleRequests/openPullRequest.json');
// decode the plaintext into an actual JSON object
$stubObject = json_decode($plaintext);
// Get the object attributes as an array instead of stdclass
$arrayContent = get_object_vars($stubObject);
$response = $this->post('/pullrequest', $arrayContent);
```

This is not guarantee that your test will pass, since we don't know how your endpoint should behave, but it basically points out the need of converting data to the proper type before using on the tester methods (`post()` in this case).